# Can not commit to local repository after making changes ( Visual Studio 2015 (Community) )

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I've created a local repository in place of my solution, created a remote repository in github , made a commit, then pushed the commit to github remote repo. Ok, good.
After that I've done some changes to the code and wanted to send them to github,
So first I should find a commit button to commit changes to the local repo, after that i suspect i need to push this to remote.
But I can not find a commit button. Instead in the Source Control submenu in solution explorer right-click menu I can only see View history,Compare with unmodified(greyed out) and Annotate
No commit.

If i go to team menu and go to changes, there is a commit button there with a textfield to write down the commit message, but this button is disabled even if i put a message. Can anyone clear this out for me? Thanks

**Answering** the first request below I've typed 
git status in the command prompt and here is what i've got

```
D:\Projects\AsmParser>git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   AsmOperand.cpp
        modified:   AsmOperandParser.cpp
        modified:   AsmOperandParser.h
        modified:   AsmOperandParserUnitTest.cpp
        modified:   AsmOperandUnitTest.cpp
        modified:   AsmRegisterUnitTest.cpp
        modified:   main.cpp

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        AsmParser.VC.opendb
        AsmParser.rar

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I guess I can do all the dirty job with command line. I'm still interested about Visual Studio problem

Comment: Can you do me a favor and type `git status` from the command prompt?  I suspect that the files you modified are not being added to the Git index.

Comment: have you save the file ? or visual studio still showing * on the file that means file is not saved so git won't have anything to commit.

Comment: Tim, updated results in the questions

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're missing the [*Add*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository) step. I haven't used Visual Studio source control integration features, but there must be a way of indicating you want to record the changes before you can actually commit something.

Try typing `git add -u` from the command prompt (to add all modified files, but not new ones) and check if you are then able to commit from Visual Studio.